# Addition Of Two table value with current date(Todays Date)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, sqlalchemy

I was trying to add sum of Total value from different tables. It's sucess with this query But I want addition of current date.

Table1                                  Table2 
Date                Total_Cost                  Date                  Total_Cost 
21/01/2015          500                         21/01/2015            500

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(Total_Cost) FROM Table1) + (SELECT SUM(Total_Cost) FROM Table2) as total
```

Its Give proper answer : 1000

But I Run this Query Addition With Current Date.

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(Total_Cost) FROM Table1 WHERE DATE =  CURDATE()) + (SELECT SUM(Total_Cost) FROM Table2 WHERE DATE =  CURDATE()) as total
```

Its Give Value :NULL

Please help me someone To solve this thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you get when you run this query?
SELECT Total_Cost FROM Table1 WHERE DATE =  CURDATE()
or this
SELECT Total_Cost FROM Table2 WHERE DATE =  CURDATE()

Comment: Your date in table2 has the year as '2105' not '2015'!

Comment: its give Today Date Total_Cost All Value, But i want Sum of Total_Cost          of two table and addition of it with current date

Answer (score 0):

Your query needs to cope with the possibility that no rows may be returned by either of your select statements (ie a NULL value) by using ISNULL eg

```
ISNULL(SELECT SUM(X) FROM Table1 WHERE Date=CURDATE(),0.0)
```

or even:

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Total_Cost),0.0) FROM 
(
  SELECT Total_Cost FROM Table1 WHERE Date = CURDATE()
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Total_Cost FROM Table2 WHERE Date = CURDATE()
) S1
```

Apologies if this is not valid MySQL syntax I'm more familiar with SQL Server, but I hope it helps even so.

Comment: but i want to addition of both Sum of Total_Cost

Comment: Second query gives this Error.                                                               #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Comment: But its not working... Gives Error...#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;